# React js After the page jumps, the page displays blank, Refused to execute script

Tags: reactjs, types, mime

After react is deployed, the home page file becomes a JavaScript file, resulting in page loading failure

What happens when the content of index.html becomes a JavaScript file suffix (the page stays still for a period of time to trigger the route)

The error message is as follows：

```
                    <MenuItem
                        as={Link}
                        to="/buyertools/order-history"
                        borderRadius="4px"
                        height="45px"
                        textColor="semantics.default"
                      >
```

One

[image]

Two
[image]

Three:
[image]

**47.d0f21705.chunk.js**  The information is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
        </script>
        <style>
            .async-hide {
                opacity: 0!important
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            !function(e, n, t, a, c, s, d, i, m) {
                n.className += " " + t,
                s.start = 1 * new Date,
                s.end = d = function() {
                    n.className = n.className.replace(RegExp(" ?" + t), "")
                }
                ,
                (e[a] = e[a] || []).hide = s,
                setTimeout((function() {
                    d(),
                    s.end = null
                }
                ), 4e3),
                s.timeout = 4e3
            }(window, document.documentElement, "async-hide", "dataLayer", 0, {
                "GTM-KWJFD3C": !0
            })
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.michaels.com" data-react-helmet="true"/>
        <meta name="title" content="Michaels Stores – Art Supplies, Crafts & Framing" data-react-helmet="true"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
 
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="assetlinks.json file" href="/.well-known/assetlinks.json"/>
        <link rel="apple-app-site-association file" href="/.well-known/apple-app-site-association"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/skl5onh.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/heatmap.js/2.0.0/heatmap.min.js" integrity="sha512-FpvmtV53P/z7yzv1TAIVH7PNz94EKXs5aV6ts/Zi+B/VeGU5Xwo6KIbwpTgKc0d4urD/BtkK50IC9785y68/AA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
   
        </script>            <link href="/static/css/main.dcb28ad8.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
       
        <script src="/static/js/43.a7174a23.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/main.4cd548f1.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Why is it a problem that the information in index.html is loaded into the JS file*

**If you keep clicking on the page, the page route can jump and render the page information**

In case of the above problems, the page can be displayed normally only after the address is refreshed

I don't know why. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your web server (nginx, apparently) seems to be misconfigured in a way that it returns the root index.html for any 404-ing URL, including those under `/static/`.

So what should probably be a 404 instead gets the index.html content (indeed, HTML), and your browser refuses to execute it as JavaScript (which it isn't).

So, firstly - fix the server configuration to return 404s for 404s under `/static/`. (For deeplinking purposes in a SPA environment, it does make sense to return index content for other URLs.)

(Looking at the fact that the site is also trying to POST to `http://undefined/`, this probably won't be the only issue you'll need to solve.)